# How can I move files from service to service?

Tags: file-transfer

Like on Chrome OS (which I've never used by the way) it's meant to be all about the cloud, how would you transport files between different web apps?

Eg I draw a flowchart in Creately, on a normal desktop I'd have to download it as an image file, and then upload it to Google Docs so I could embed the image on a word document.

But on a cloud-based OS, how can you download it to the local computer, which you're not meant to be able to do as that defeats the point of the cloud a bit?

Why hasn't anyone come up with a common protocol to enable web app <> web app communication?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Extension [Cloud Save](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/omiekjeapoonbhiemenfoccbdpeagdah) facilitates this to some degree. ([Review](http://lifehacker.com/#!5778231/cloud-save-uploads-images-and-files-to-the-cloud-with-a-right-click))

It's limited to services with an API (Dropbox, Google Docs, box.net, plus several more) but I expect more to be added.

I've been using it on my Cr-48 and it has made that device infinitely more useful.

Answer (score 0):

When we say service to service, can't one base64 encode the data and send it across to the other service which can then base64 decode the data. Base64 probably is not the only way using which files can be sent. For instance, once the flowchar is done the image can be saved to a cloud and from the same cloud the other service can pick it up. I think common protocol is already there.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand any of that? Each service has there own storage, you can either save there or save to your hard drive. I want to go in to a service like creature and save to something like google docs, skydive or dropbox online.

Comment: If the data can be saved onto a service it means it can retrieved back right ? So when you are communicating with the service you extract that saved information and save it Google Docs or SkyeDirve or Dropbox.

Comment: As for the how should the data be saved. The most common way data is sent between services would XML. To store a complete file in XML you would need encode it using Base64. Once your service gets the encoded data you can decode it and get the file back.

Answer (score 0):

Primadesk seems to be the exact answer to this question, however it is not public yet.